# Clearing US custom at Toronto Pearson YYZ at 5am?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, air-canada, pre-clearance, yyz

According to [here](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-arrival/locations/canada) the US Customs service at Toronto Pearson YYZ only opens at 6 am. Nevertheless, Air Canada has flights at 6+ am to New York. In that case, how could you clear the border and board the flight?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those hours are wrong and preclearance is open earlier than that.

Comment: I agree with Michael. If they have scheduled flights (which they do) that operate at that time then they surely have US officers to process them

Comment: The site you linked does not list hours of opereation of the Customs service.  Looking carefully at the navigation bar with >> symbols near the top of the page (and also at the URL), the page describes availability of enrolment for the "Global Entry" program at these locations.

Comment: Thanks all. Normally how long does it take to clear the border ? I am PR with French passport (eligible ETA) and not Canadian. I am asking since I would have to take night bus 300 from Toronto to the airport. Flight is supposed to be at 6h30, what time do you think I should arrive at the airport ? @AriBrodsky what is this Global Entry and how is it different from other types of entry ? My apologies for the amateur questions; my first time going to US.

Comment: I generally go with 2x the usual security clearance delay. 3hrs in advance is generally safe if you do not have Global Entry.

Comment: I believe you have linked the wrong information. The link appears to be when the Global Entry _office_ is open at those airports. For Toronto, given the dense flight schedule and likelihood of delays, inspection is probably happening around the clock.

Comment: Could you share what exactly is this **Global Entry** program ? I thought it means ordinary custom.

Answer (score 7):

Just [7 days ago](https://twitter.com/LisaCarlesso/status/1227724349110657026) from the time of posting this *@TorontoPearson* tweeted:

> **Customs open at 3:30 am** and counters are open 3 hours prior to scheduled flight times.  Hope this helps.  Regards.

Therefore, the hours you listed are out of date.